# Does Continuity of Composite Functions hold for both ways?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Define two statements as follows, where $a$ is any number in both of their domain.

$p$ : $f \circ g$ is continuous at $x = a$.

$q$ : $g$ is continuous at $x = a$, and $f$ is continuous at $x = g(a)$.

I know that if $q$ holds then $p$ holds to. Does the opposite hold too? I feel like its trivial but I have no way to confirm it.

Comment: no it doesn’t. let f be constant. then p always holds, for every possible g

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$p$ doesn't imply $q$ :

$f(x) =\begin{cases} \frac{1}{x} &x\neq 0 \\0& x=0\end{cases}$

Then $f\circ f=\operatorname{id}$

$f\circ f$ continuous at $0$ but $f$ is not continuous at $0$.

For another example choose $g(x) =\begin{cases}\sin \frac{1}{x} &x\neq 0 \\0& x=0\end{cases}$

Then $g\circ f(x) =\sin x$